# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken - Push Notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I just wanted to confirm "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" is meant to be called everytime the application loads and my PHP server or application needs to deal with whether or not to resubmit to store in my database? Or is there something I am missing?

Thanks
James

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, you are not meant to call this method directly. Rather, you should call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` on every launch of your app which then in turn calls `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` which you must implement.

Second, yes, you are supposed to resubmit the token to your server every time. From the documentation:

> By requesting the device token and passing it to the provider every time your application launches, you help to ensure that the provider has the current token for the device. If a user restores a backup to a device other than the one that the backup was created for (for example, the user migrates data to a new device), he or she must launch the application at least once for it to receive notifications again. If the user restores backup data to a new device or reinstalls the operating system, the device token changes. Moreover, never cache a device token and give that to your provider; always get the token from the system whenever you need it. If your application has previously registered, calling registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: results in iOS passing the device token to the delegate immediately without incurring additional overhead.

Comment: Thank you - Just for clarification I did not call the "application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" I was meaning it got called as a delegate method.