# "Myapp would like to send you push notifications" message not appearing in my app, but it still allows push notifications to appear

Tags: ios, push-notification

As the title says, when I first start up my app the dialog asking the user whether or not they want to receive push notifications doesn't appear. However if you go into settings the app appears in the push noticifications section, and the app DOES receive the push notification.

I'm using this to register for push, have I missed something out:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];`

I'm led to believe that if this is in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions that the prompt for the user would automatically appear?

Edit: I forgot to add that I do also have a didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken function in there too, to retain the token. As I say the notifications work in the sense that the user receives them, but the "do you want to receive them" popup never appears - which I would imagine are grounds for rejection by Apple.

Comment: So when you delete the application from the device and then re-install, you are saying that it is here it isn't asking again?

Comment: That's right. It seems to automatically approve the notification registration.

Comment: I think that is the expected behaviour to be honest, I can't recall seeing any different.  Unless you change your Bundle ID, I think it will remain authorised. (Or if it was disabled when you deleted it)

Comment: I just re-read your first comment, it's not just after reinstalling that it didn't ask for authorisation to use push messages. It NEVER asked at all, the very first time I ran the app it just approved push notifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this is needed to retain the token:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
NSString *token = [[[deviceToken description]
                        stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]]
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                       withString:@""];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", token] forKey:@"DeviceToken"];

    NSLog(@"APNs Device Token: %@", token);
}
```

See this thread also: [didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken - Push Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804148/didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-push-notifications)

Comment: Oops I do have that in the code itself, but forgot to add it here. Thanks for reminding me, I've edited the question now.

Comment: Additionally, it seems it WAS working all along. When I gave it to other people to test, they were asked if they wanted to accept push notifications. My device still wasn't asking me even when I uninstalled and reinstalled. Then after changing the product name and reinstalling - it suddenly asked me! I presume it did ask me the very first time, and then remembered even between installs.

Comment: @TheBestBigAl, Just to confirm that this happened to me as well. The way I deal with it is to reset the device... We should not have to do these kind of things just to test...